# Cuando ejecuto en VSCode no ejecuta nada?

Tags: python, tkinter, vscode, macos

Detalles importantes: **Estoy Utilizando Mac**.

Hice un "hola mundo" y eso si lo muestra en la consola. La carpeta tiene dos archivos, uno llamado ventana y el otro principal. Se hizo el `import` de de `tkinter` normal, pero no me ejecuta nada y **tampoco devuelve error en consola**, ni el profe del curso me pudo ayudar.

El código esta bien, por que es el que utilizamos en clase y está igual.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Archivo ventanas:

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import messagebox
     class ventana(Frame):
        def __init__(self, master:None): 
          super().__init__(master, height=500, width=400, background="gray")
          self.master
          self.pack()
          self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        marco=Frame(self,bg="red")
        marco.place(x=0,y=0, width=400,height=300)

        lblNombre=Label(marco,text="Nombre",font=("arial blak", 10), bg="gray" )
        lblNombre.place(x=5,y=5,width=75,height=20)

        self.txtNombre=Entry(marco)
        self.txtNombre.place(x=80,y=5, width=100,height=20)

        self.btnCapturar=Button(marco,text="Ingresar", bg="green",             width=20,height=20)
        self.btnCapturar.place(x=40, y=30, width=100, height=30)

        self.cmbLista=ttk.Combobox(marco, values=["Opcion 1","Opcion 2", "Opcion 3"])
        self.cmbLista.place(x=5,y=70,width=100,height=30)
        self.cmbLista.current(1)

        self.tblInformacion=ttk.Treeview(marco,columns=["col0","col1","col2"])

        self.tblInformacion.column("#0",width=100)
        self.tblInformacion.column("#1",width=100)
        self.tblInformacion.column("#2",width=100)

        self.tblInformacion.heading("#0",text="#")
        self.tblInformacion.column("#1",text="Nombre")
        self.tblInformacion.column("#2",text="Telefono")

        self.tblInformacion.pack()
        barraVertical=Scrollbar(self.tblInformacion, orient=VERTICAL)
        barraVertical.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.tblInformacion.config(yscrollcommand=barraVertical.set)
        barraVertical.config(command=YView)
        self.tblInformacion.place(x=5,y=300)

        for i in range(1,100,1):
            self.tblInformacion.insert("", END, text=str(i),values=                 ["Nombre","Telefono"])


    def bienvenidos(self):
        nombre=self.txtNombre.get()

        messagebox.showinfo(title="Bienvenidos", message="Bienvenido"+nombre)


    from tkinter import *
    from ventanas import *

    def main():
      root = Tk()
      root.wm_title("Mi apliacion")
      app =ventana(root)

      barraMenu=Menu(root)
      subMenuArchivo=(barraMenu)
      subMenuArchivo.add_command(label="Guardar")
      subMenuArchivo.add_separator()
      barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Menu", menu=subMenuArchivo)

      subMenuEditor=Menu(barraMenu)
      subMenuEditor.add_command(label="Editar")

      barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Archivo")
      barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Editar")


      root.config(menu=barraMenu)



      app.mainloop()
      root.mainloop()

      if __name__=="__main__":
          main()
```

Comment: Entiendo que la indentación incorrecta se debe a que no se copió el código correctamente. Por eso pregunto, en tu código original, el `if __name__...` está dentro o fuera de la función main?

Answer (score 0):

Veo que estás importando ventanas pero tú clase se llama ventana, son esos detalles sencillos que se pierden entre todo el codigo

Comment: o sea.. es un error tipografico???

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene algunos problemitas...
Vamos con una sección del **main**:

```
barraMenu=Menu(root)
subMenuArchivo=(barraMenu)
subMenuArchivo.add_command(label="Guardar")
subMenuArchivo.add_separator()
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Menu", menu=subMenuArchivo)
```

Un error mínimo, que hace que tu código no llegue a arrancar...
creas un **Menu** llamado **barraMenu**
le haces una copia (**subMenuArchivo=(barraMenu)**)
a la copia le agregas un comando
al original le agregas como sub-menú, la copia

osea es sub-menú de si mismo, lo que hace "crashear" tu programa (curiosamente, no arroja ningún error).
Deberías hacerlo así:

```
barraMenu = Menu(root)
subMenuArchivo = Menu(root)
subMenuArchivo.add_command(label="Guardar")
subMenuArchivo.add_separator()
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Menu", menu=subMenuArchivo)
```

Ahora veamos la clase **Ventana**.
Antes que nada, corregí la identación en la declaración de la clase.

Cuando intentas ejecutar, te salta un error en las siguientes lineas:

```
self.tblInformacion.column("#1",text="Nombre")
self.tblInformacion.column("#2",text="Telefono")
```

deberías usar lo mismo que la linea anterior, osea:

```
self.tblInformacion.heading("#0",text="#")
self.tblInformacion.heading("#1",text="Nombre")
self.tblInformacion.heading("#2",text="Telefono")
```

Luego de las pequeñas correcciones, todo funciona bien.